# How to install a printer that is connected via an USB-to-Parallel-Port adapter?

Tags: linux, drivers, usb, printing, parallel-port

I'm running [Sabayon](http://sabayon.org) Linux (x86_64).

```
$ uname -a
Linux qdoe 3.7.0-sabayon #1 SMP Thu Dec 20 07:12:55 UTC 2012 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3930K CPU @ 3.20GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

I have a HP LaserJet 1100 printer which by default is connected via an 25-pin parallel printer port ([DB25](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_port)). Now, I have a new computer without such a port and I'm not able to directly connect the printer.

Therefore, I bought an USB-to-DB25-connector and tried to install my printer.

[image: USB-to-DB25-connector]

But here the trouble starts. In Sabayon or Gentoo, there is a toolbox for HP printers called [`hplip`](https://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Install_a_HP_Printer) which is very easy to use: connect printer, detect it with `hplip` and you are ready to go.

[image: hplip]

Now the issue is, that the `hplip` software does not recognize the printer. Neither via USB nor via parallel port (LPT). The port seems to work though:

```
# lsusb
(...)
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 067b:2305 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2305 Parallel Port
```

I already tried to manually enter the USB address `067b:2305` into `hplip` - but no success, the printer is not recognized.

What else can I do? Is there some kind of further port-emulation software or any drivers I need in addition to make this port work with my printer?

Comment: I haven't seen such a beast, but it should behave like a paralell port, just probably with a weird name. Try to find out what it is named, and see if you can enter that. Perhaps you'd have to find out exactly what files the tool modifies (perhaps `strace` helps here) and hack the paralell name's port in. It would be nice if you reported your problems and solution to your distribution to update hplip.

Comment: There are two major changes to the musb.c code in the HPLIP io/hpmud. 1. Obtain the printer identification by reading the string from the printer itself and not the usb device. The usb device simply reports IEEE1284 for the Prolific.
2. When closing the raw channel, clear the halt condition on the in/out endpoints. For HPLIP 3.23.3, please see the bug report at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/1235563

Answer (score 3):

http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/CUPS

If you are using a USB->Parallel adapter, you'll want to do the following:

```
Add your printer by selecting a different connection type (since usb and parallel will not be listed)
Edit the file /etc/cups/printers.conf
Change the DeviceID line to read: DeviceID = parallel:/dev/usb/lp0
...actually, it looks like the proper line is now: DeviceURI parallel:/dev/usb/lp0
```

Note: that it is "parallel:" NOT "usb:" - the USB part is handled by the usb drivers. To CUPS it should show up as a parallel port. CUPS doesn't know to look for USB->Parallel adapters, but if you manually configure it, it will work

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I dont have a `/etc/cups/printers.conf` file. Creating one, adding that line and restarting cupsd didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, hplip does not support USB to parallel adapters - see for example http://www.mail-archive.com/hplip-help@lists.sourceforge.net/msg02858.html

I managed to get a parallel printer connected via a PL2305 adapter like yours to work with CUPS by manually editing the printers.conf file as described by @Sandro kensan - I am looking at the CUPS 'Printer Test Page' right now, so I can confirm that Sandro kensan's method works.

I suspect that the absence of printers.conf on your machine means that you do not have CUPS installed. I recommend you do not attempt to create this entire file from scratch; it consists of much more than a single line.

As for HPLIP -  I have been completely unable to get it to recognise my LaserJet 2100 connected via a PL2305. What follows is what I've tried so far, in the hope it saves you some time.

Firstly, I tried specifying the USB bus:device numbers of the PL2305 to hp-setup's command line. That results in hp-setup walking the entire USB device tree, at times reading data from USB devices then closing them again, then finally outputting

```
error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.
```

and exiting with nonzero status. I suspect it was sniffing each device to see whether it smelt like an HP printer, deciding none were, and giving up.

Secondly, I tried to set the printer up as a parallel printer. Comments elsewhere online said this would not work but as USB had already failed I decided to try it.

The first problem you encounter with this approach is that hp-setup wants to scan rather than be told the device node to use. To defeat this, you have to run it from the command line and supply the device node as an argument.

The next problem is that hp-setup only recognises the command-line argument as a parallel port device node (as opposed, for example, to a USB bus:device ID) if it is in the form /dev/partport[0-9]. I defeated that by doing:

```
sudo ln -s /dev/usb/lp1 /dev/parport1
```

That could be made persistent using a custom udev rule, but it's an ugly hack.

The next problem is that the HPLIP tools then (rightly) assume that /dev/parport1 is an lp device, and issue parallel-specific ioctls such as PPGETMODES on it. The kernel driver for the PL2305 is not 'parallel-ish' enough to understand these, so returns an error code, which causes the HPLIP tools to skip that device node, in the process outputting more cryptic/useless diagnostics such as:

```
Invalid device URI
```

As far as I can tell, HPLIP wants to see either:

1. A USB device which is an HP brand printer (not a adaptor/bridge behind which sits a printer); or
2. An 'lp'-like device node representing a parallel port, which supports all of the parallel-specific ioctls.

The /dev/usb/lp[0-9] device nodes we get when we plug in our PL2305s are neither of these, and HPLIP can't handle them itself, and is inflexible such that it supplies no way I can see for you to force it to Do The Right Thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've just opened [a bug report](https://www.cups.org/str.php?L4765%20P-1%20S-2%20C0%20I0%20E0%20Q), with attached a working `/etc/cups/printers.conf` for recent versions of Debian:

```
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v1.5.3
# Written by cupsd
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<Printer HP_LaserJet_1100>
UUID urn:uuid:e2fd8b09-9e4e-3f96-79ac-f16946700768
Info 
Location 
MakeModel HP LaserJet 1100 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9
DeviceURI parallel:/dev/usb/lp1
State Idle
StateTime 1454272978
Type 4116
Accepting Yes
Shared No
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>
```

Please note that you have to stop CUPS before editing/replacing/creating this file.

I think my device is `lp1` because I also have a real parallel port on this PC (`/dev/lp0`). In any case you can find the right device with:

```
# ls /dev/usb/lp*
```

Comment: Please note that we like to have self-contained answers here. Of course the link to the bug report can be included.

Answer (score 0):

## Parallel physical connection

First of all you need to check your printer [parallel port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_port) connector (also known as *Centronics* or *IEEE-1284*).

Normally that should be a micro ribbon 36-pin **female socket**.
Your PC should instead have a mini-Centronics 36-pin **male** connector.

As your PC seems not to have one, you use a USB adapter, just like ton one you have shown.

Thus, a host-to-device parallel cable is needed which has a micro ribbon 36-pin **male plug** on one side and a mini-Centronics 36-pin **female** connector on the other one. That's normally called a *parallel cable*, a *Centronics cable* or a *printer cable*.

So your physical setup requires two things:

- a USB-to-Centronics* adapter (which it seems you already own) and
- a parallel cable.

As an option, you could have a *USB printer adapter*  which terminates in a micro ribbon 36-pin **male plug** and which would connect directly a PC USB port to the printer's parallel socket.

In either case, you are using a parallel port on your PC. Being it a real one or a USB-adapted one is irrelevant.

A **USB printer** is something totally different as it doesn't have a parallel/Centronics/IEEE-1284 port but natively uses the [USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) standard on either side of the connection.

## Parallel logical connection

Once all this is done, in either way, you need to setup a **parallel printer**. It doesn't matter whether you use a USB adapter or not. Your PC "*sees*" a parallel port and you have to use that standard.

If you had a USB printer, then you should have been setting up a **USB printer** because it's a USB-native printer (which covers most of the cases nowadays).

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread and tried everything here but it didn't work for me.

What did work follows:

My setup:
Raspberry Pi 3 running Arch Linux.
HP Laserjet 5p (A freaking workhorse printer I didn't want to throw away.)

My RPI is headless so I had to rely on the command line. I was able to tunnel to the Raspberry Pi and use the CUPS web interface but try as I might, it wouldn't let me administer the printer. In the end, I doubt I could have installed it through the GUI interface anyway. FWIW, to tunnel to CUPS on the PI from my workstation running Arch, I used this command:

```
#ssh your_user@your_rpi -T -L 3631:localhost:631
```

This is a reasonable rehash of what worked. Though understand, I hacked at this for a couple of days. The cups documentation was very helpful for some of the command line stuff.

1. Determine the list of printer drivers on your Pi. It can be a long list so whittle it down with a couple or three "greps"

   sudo lpinfo -m

For my LJ5P, it was this: (Syntax for the following "lpadmin" command was important.)

```
drv:///hp/hpcups.drv/hp-laserjet_5p.ppd HP LaserJet 5p, hpcups 3.21.6
```

2. Install the printer using "lpadmin": (You can name your printer whatever you wish with the "-P" switch.)

   sudo lpadmin -p HP-LaserJet-5p -E -v socket:localhost -m drv:/hp/hpcups.drv/hp-laserjet_5p.ppd
3. List the available backends and printers

   sudo lpinfo -v

This is where I found:

```
direct usb://HP/LaserJet%205P
```

4. Stop cups and edit "/etc/cups/printers.conf" and replace the line for "DeviceURI". in my case, it was:

   DeviceURI usb://HP/LaserJet%205P
5. Start cups however your distro dictates.
6. You should be able to print.